# Listing all connected iDevices in Cocoa

Tags: iphone, cocoa, volume, iokit, diskarbitration

I want to implement a sort of backup feature for my backup app, but since I can not do that on the device, I have to do it on the Mac. How would I go about listing the connected iDevices (iPhone and iPod Touch mainly) on the computer? I assume I could go and enumerate through some huge array of all connected USB devices and check for ones that have the Apple vendor code, but I know there's some better way.

I also assume I must use IOKit for this, but I've never worked with it, so I'd appreciate some sample code, and useful tips to point me in the right direction. Then, I'd need to get the device name, and access the files on the device, but I suppose that's gonna be simple after I figure out the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [Disk Arbitration Framework](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/). This (relatively new) framework is being frequently updated to correspond to new hardware advances in the iThing world...

Have fun!

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation for this framework, but I assume that it is public. Do you have any idea where the docs might have gone?

Comment: apparently there is a bit of internal conflict in the docs as to whether disk is spelled 'disk' or 'disc'  which leads to some strange/dead links...  try here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/DiskArbitration_h/